# What does it mean when a message's contentes are replaced by "Malware name: 'EngineError'"

Tags: exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a blocked email with a malware name “EngineError” indicate a flaw in Forefront Protection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7422/does-a-blocked-email-with-a-malware-name-engineerror-indicate-a-flaw-in-forefro)

A privious post on this topic was closed as "unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet"; however, since then (Sept 23, 2009) I've see this many times in many different geographies, all related to Microsoft's Forefront Protection.

I'm unable to find much solid information.  Someone appeared to have some information about MFP, but that information is not readily available since the topic was closed.

Any additional information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe the question you're referring to is here.  http://security.stackexchange.com/q/7422/485  The question is still of fairly narrow use, and does not appear to be an actual "security" question - it seems your problem is with the usability and/or functionality of a specific application, not any issue particularly concerning (as the [FAQ] says) "protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities".  If the question is to be answered at all, I suggest two things:  1) Delete this question.  It's a stub.  2) Request the other thread be unlocked and migrated to [su] or [sf].

Comment: Will delete this one. Do you want the other one migrated to SU or SF as per @Iszi's comment?